# How to get the one before last element of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanna to get one before last element of array in JavaScript. but in console, when I use this code "`array.length -2`"dose not work, and it just return me the length of array minus 2.
and when I use this code "`array.at[-2]`" it returns "undefined"!

Comment: If the array is: `arr = [1,2,3];` then please try: `console.log(arr.at(-2));`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
console.log(arr[arr.length -2])
//5
```